# Error validating datasource db while using prisma data platform

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-data-platform

I am running into an issue in my `schema.prisma` file. I configured my app to use prisma data proxy and used the provided `prisma://....` connection string as the `DATABASE_URL` connection string. However, When I tried migrating the models by `npx prisma migrate dev`

I got this error

```
Error: Get config: Schema Parsing P1012
error: Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `postgresql://` or `postgres://`.
--> schema.prisma:8
|
7 | provider = "postgresql"
8 | url = env("DATABASE_URL")
|
Validation Error Count: 1
```

Comment: Did you solve this error? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the direct database connection string ( not starting with prisma:// ) to use migrate commands.